# Sorting (ORDER BY) rows from Shapefile using Python?

Tags: python, shapefile, ogr2ogr, fiona

I'm writing a Python script where I have to read a Shapefile, sort its rows/records by a specific field, and then write a new shapefile with that new order.

Does anyone how can I do it?

I'm using Fiona to open the file but I can't find out how I can do an so easy and common operation as an ORDER BY.

**EDIT**

The solution proposed by @Jose works perfectly right. But geopandas doesn't create the *.prj* file that contains the projection description and this is a problem if you need it. A possible solution could be just copy the original file with the new name:

```py
import os
import geopandas as gpd

def main(file, field):
    output_file_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0] + '_sorted_by_' + field + os.path.splitext(file)[1]

    shape = gpd.read_file(file)
    shape_sorted = shape.iloc[shape[field].sort_values().index.values]
    shape_sorted.to_file(driver='ESRI Shapefile', filename=output_file_name)

    # Copy prj file
    prj_file = os.path.splitext(file)[0] + '.prj'

    if os.path.isfile(prj_file):
        from shutil import copyfile
        output_prj_file_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0] + '_sorted_by_' + field + '.prj'
        copyfile(prj_file, output_prj_file_name)
```

Finally I decided to use a ogr2ogr command with `-sql` argument and execute it in Python using `os.system(command)` utility.

```py
import os

def main(file, field):
    output_file_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0] + '_sorted_by_' + field + os.path.splitext(file)[1]
    file_object = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]

    command = 'ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM ' + file_object + ' ORDER BY ' + field + '" ' + output_file_name + ' ' + file

    os.system(command)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: If you just need to sort the file and it does not need to be with Python you could use this MapServer utility https://mapserver.org/utilities/sortshp.html.

Comment: Load your records into a list and then use python's [built-in sorting with a key function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).

Comment: ogr2ogr can read/write shapefiles, it has a sql option you can issue an Order By to sort a shapefile. Not Python specific.

Comment: @klewis thanks for your suggestion. A combination of ogr2ogr and Python was what I finally decided to use. Thanks

Comment: I don't have that issue with the prj file, @LuisSP, maybe if you set the crs with `shape.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}` or `shape.to_file(crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'})`

Comment: @LuisSP are you ussing Python2? Geopandas only supports Python3

Comment: @Jose I'm using Python3. I don't want to set the CRS manually because the script has just to order the rows, It doesn't has to modify anything else. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use geopandas, if you use pandas you will be familiar with this library:

```
import geopandas as gpd

shapefile_path = 'path_to_your_file/your_file.shp'
shape = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)
shape_sorted = shape.iloc[shape['YOUR FIELD'].sort_values().index.values]
shape_sorted.to_file(driver='ESRI Shapefile', filename='output_file.shp')
```